# Apps Script - 2 Conditions in if Statement. If Cell changes & if Cell contains certain text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this function below

How can I show "please select" in cell D4 when cell A4 has been changed and does not contain the text "SS".

Also, how can I show the value of B4 in cell D4 when cell A4 has been changed and does contain the text "SS", and then highlight the cell in yellow with a red font.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  
  var Grade = (e.range.getColumn() === 1 ) && ( e.range.getRow() === 4); // cell A4
  var CustomMaterial= (e.range.getColumn() === 2 ) && ( e.range.getRow() === 4); // cell B4
  var Size = (e.range.getColumn() === 3 ) && ( e.range.getRow() === 4); // cell C4
  var Material= (e.range.getColumn() === 4 ) && ( e.range.getRow() === 4); // cell D4
  
  
  try {
    let sheet = e.range.getSheet()
    if( sheet.getName() === "mycalc" ) {
      
      if(Grade && Grade! "*SS*) { 
      sheet.getRange("Size").setValue("Please Select");
      sheet.getRange("Material").setValue("Please Select");
         }

}
      if(Grade && Grade=="*SS*) { 
      sheet.getRange("Size").setValue("Please Select");
      sheet.getRange("Material").setValue(CustomMaterial);
         }

        }
     catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("onEdit() "+err);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error here: `if(Grade && Grade! "*SS*) { `

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.match()`, like this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    let sheet;
    if (e.range.rowStart !== 4
      || e.range.columnStart > 4
      || (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName() !== 'mycalc') {
      return;
    }
    const d4 = sheet.getRange('D4');
    switch (e.range.columnStart) {
      case 1:
        if (e.value.match(/SS/i)) {
          const b4Value = sheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
          d4.setValue(b4Value).setBackground('yellow').setFontColor('red');
        } else {
          d4.setValue('please select').setBackground(null).setFontColor(null);
        }
        break;
      default:
        ;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(`onEdit(e) error: ${err.message}`);
  }
}
```

The `switch()` control flow statement is a bit much for this simple example. It anticipates that you require more logic depending on which column was edited.